# How to use Views PHP to code if a view exists and has content then echo...

Tags: views

I have a view displaying a list a menu of all the content for a node. It contains a list of all the fields and views on the page, with the output rewritten as a link eg link to field A . 
I can do this fine for each field but I also have a view 'teachers' exposed as a block. If the view has content I want to have a link to it in the menu. 
I'm trying to use Views PHP to code if the view has content, echo ''
What function do I call to see if the view exists and has content?
I've tried if(views_get_view('teachers) == TRUE){ echo "";} but this always returns TRUE even if there is no content for that view for a specific node.

I want to do something similar to

Answer (score 2):

You can look at [views_get_view_result()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view_result/) and do something like this:

```
$result=views_get_view_result('teachers');
if (isset($result[0])) {
  // we have results
} else {
  // we don't
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done simpler without querying for a result

```
$view = views_get_view('my_view_name');
if($view) {
  //continue logic..
}
```